# parse string with many spaces in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like `"Azarenke   V.   Su   Simple 90"` and I need to split it and put all words in array.
I using this code:

```
var s = "Azarenke   V.   Su   Simple 90";

var array = s.split(/(\ +)/);
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

but the result is:

```
"["Azarenke","   ","V.","   ","Su","   ","Simple"," ","90"]"
```

Where is some 'empty' strings contains only spaces. But I do not whant to push them in output array. I familiar in C# and .net, it has something like `RemoveEmptyEntries` but can't find the same in javascript. How to solve this task? Possible I need to make some remarks in regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the capturing group. Capturing group will keep up the delimiters. That is , it splits the input according to the delimiter and also it prints out the delimiter at the final.

```
> var s = "Azarenke   V.   Su   Simple 90";
undefined
> s.split(/\s+/);
[ 'Azarenke',
  'V.',
  'Su',
  'Simple',
  '90' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try without (capturing) parens

```
var s = "Azarenke   V.   Su   Simple 90";

var array = s.split(/\s+/);
console.log(JSON.stringify(array)); 
// Output:  ["Azarenke","V.","Su","Simple","90"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace multiple spaces with single spaces first, using:

```
`Azarenke   V.   Su   Simple 90`.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'');
```

Then you can split by a space.